# SQLite database managing Objective C

Tags: objective-c, database, sqlite, primary-key

I have an sqlite table for saving Survey Answers with QuestionId(primary key) and Answers as columns. I have a matrix type question whose answer i get from server is a set of all rows in that particular matrix. but i need to save in individual rows as i show each rowQuestion and its answers in different screen/pages.

Suppose i have a matrix type question A with three rows a,b,c. I will show Question A with row 'a' in Page1. I will show Question A with row 'b' in page2. I will show Question A with row 'c' in page3.

But i get the answer for Question A as a full set (answers of row'a','b','c').
But i need to save it individually on separate rows but there occurs a clash in the Question Id(its the same for all three rows) and it gets overwritten.

Please suggest me an option to maintain a separate Primary key -say the page number.

Comment: Please provide some samples of the data you have and of your desired data. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: Why you use `objective-c` tag here? Question is related to SQL.